# I am stuck with the concept of fading in and out in jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, for-loop

I am developing an online test application and I am extracting all the questions from the 
xml file to a jsp page...All the questions are displayed using a for loop in jsp...
Now i don`t want all the questions in a single page , rather i want them one by one to be displayed as the user clicks the "next" button . So here is the code what i am using and it is 
displaying only the first and the 2nd question and from the 3rd question on ,, its fading in and again fading out ...without clicking the "next " button...need some suggestions here...thanks...
HERE IS THE CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var questions;      
    var counter;
    var totalQuestions;
    var currentQuestion=0;
    var i=0;                        
    totalQuestions=$("#javapaperlist").val();
    questions=$(".questions");
    questions.hide();   
    $(questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn(1000); 
    $('#next').click(function(){
        $(questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn(1000);
            $(questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(2000);
            currentQuestion=currentQuestion+1;
            $(questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn(1000);

        });
)};
```

METHOD="post">

```
<%

    for(int i = 0; i < javapaperList.size(); i++){
        JavaPaper paper = javapaperList.get(i);
        String text = paper.getText();
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(text, "##");
        int tokensint = tokens.countTokens();

%>

<div class="questions" id=<%out.println("qx" + paper.getId());%> style="display:none" > 

<%
            while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            %>  
                <label class="questiontext" ><%=tokens.nextToken()%></label><br>
         <%             
            }
         %>

         <BR>
         <BR>
         <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="A" id=<% out.println("A" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
         <% out.println(paper.getOptiona());%>
        <BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="B" id=<% out.println("B" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
        <% out.println(paper.getOptionb());%>
        <BR> 
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="C" id=<% out.println("C" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
        <% out.println(paper.getOptionc());%>
        <BR>
         <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="D" id=<% out.println("D" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
         <% out.println(paper.getOptiond());%>
        <BR> 
         <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="E" id=<% out.println("E" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
         <% out.println(paper.getOptione());%>
         <br>
         <br>
        <textarea name="<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%>" id=<% out.println("q" + paper.getId()); %>  style="display:none" onClick="clearContents(this)"><%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%></textarea>
        <br>

        <%
        if(b!=false||x==10){
            x++;
            %>
             <BR> </div>
                <input type="button" id="next" value="NEXT"  ></input>
                <BR>         
            <%
        }
      }
        %>
        <input type='hidden' value=<%out.println(javapaperList.size());%> id="javapaperlist"/>



        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </FORM>
```

Comment: Where is `});` for document.ready ??Give some html to see

Comment: well , that got misprinted...actually the problem is not that...because the code is running fine,,only some conceptual error..

Comment: Your html? give us to see

Comment: hey i am again priting this question..with some html and jquery both..

Comment: here is the code : search this string in search box : "issue with fading in and out in jQuery";

Comment: Why don't you do `questions.eq(currentQuestion)`? ( I may be missing something? )

Comment: Hey man you can edit this question don't put extra question for this one http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @ShawnG : I have used both "get " and "eq " ,,,none of them work , after the 2nd question..the 3rd question appears and then disappears automatically...

Comment: @dholakiyaankit : yeah sure ,,,actually i didn`t know,,I am new to Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0):

**simple example for fadein,fadeout,fadetoggle**

**fadein:**

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#div1").fadeIn();
  $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

**fadeout:**

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#div1").fadeOut();
  $("#div2").fadeOut("slow");
  $("#div3").fadeOut(3000);
});
```

**fadeToggle:**

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#div1").fadeToggle();
  $("#div2").fadeToggle("slow");
  $("#div3").fadeToggle(3000);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your time Mr.G,,,i will tell you what is happening exactly ,,, everything working fine till the 2nd question but when i click "next" again for the 3rd question nothing gets displayed...

Answer (score 0):

You may fadein the next question after fadeouted the previous one,not at the same time,
and you may change your id of the "next" buttons, they all have the same id,and the click event only bind to the first one.so you may change id selector to class selector, Try this:

```
<input type="button" name="next" value="NEXT" class="next"  >

$('.next').click(function () {
    $(questions.get(currentQuestion)).stop().fadeOut(2000, function () {
        currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        $(questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot chris...i have tried this too...and the problem was that the code stops running if I put the " currentQuestion= currentQuestion + 1; " statement before the  " $(questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn(1000); "

Comment: i will tell you what is happening exactly ,,, everything working fine till the 2nd question but when i click "next" again for the 3rd question nothing gets displayed...

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe there are some points else I don't get from your code, you may try @ShawnG's code,I think his better.

Comment: Oh,my pleasure..maybe you could post your html code, I tested mine and @ShawnG's codes, they are both OK, maybe the problem is in your html code..I think.

Comment: I found another issue from your html code and edited my answer, you may try it.

Comment: thanks ,but what did you edit in your code...it looks the same as before,,,it`s still giving me the same result...

Comment: Are you sure you use $('.next') instead of $('#next')?

Comment: if you find any mistakes in the html code...do let me know..any doubts  / or any queries regarding my code....so that you can help me out in a better way,,,and thanks for your time and help..

Comment: yes i used $('.next') and created a class="next" and changed the id to some other id...

Comment: no no no,,,u didn`t get it Chris,,,the button is printed only once,,,because i have put a condition in my for loop that this <input type= "button ....> gets executed only once in the entire looping..

Comment: Oh you are right, but why don't you put it out of your loop?...but it's not the point to solve the problem..I think it's a simple problem if I could debug it directly but now I've no idea, I'm sorry.

Comment: thanks for so much of your time Chris,,..i tried running the debugging thing in eclipse ,,,but it supports only java code...is there any way to debug the jQuery and the javascript code...

Comment: You could use the browser google Chrome,open the page and press F12 then turn to the "sources" tab, then you can debug your js codes, very easy.

Comment: :i got the error...i blocked all the next button in the loop while using the class="next " . you were right Chris.thanks a lot.

Comment: So the problem is solved?I'm glad to see that, and you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

On `#next` click you could just assign the current question to a variable and use `.next()`

Also, I would us `.eq()` instead of `.get()` because it prevents recalling jQuery each and every time

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var questions;      
    var counter;
    var totalQuestions;
    var currentQuestion=0;
    var i=0;                        
    totalQuestions=$("#javapaperlist").val();
    questions=$(".questions");
    questions.hide();   
    questions.eq(currentQuestion).fadeIn(1000); 
    $('#next').click(function (){
        var current = questions.eq(currentQuestion);
        current.stop().fadeOut(2000).next().fadeIn(1000);
        currentQuestion++;
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b563F/

Comment: There, sorry, I posted the code that  worked for me, based on the code you provided

Comment: I had a small error in my example, it should allow you to continue with the following questions

Comment: i mean if u go through my code,,,its bad code,,,but the 3rd question gets printed and then fades off automatically...some conceptual mistake,,,but i have tried a lot of different codes possible,,,if u have any more suggestions,, do help me out..thanks a lot..

Comment: If you could, you could create a fiddle with your html output and the current javascript that is giving you trouble

Comment: plz search this string in questions search box : " issue with fading in and fading out"  I have the whole jsp there....

Comment: ahhh try changing the id of `#next` in your html to a class and then change your javascript `$('#next').click` to `$('.next').click`